# ANGULAR. Send array data get it of Itunes API; from component-search to component-main, via service

Tags: javascript, angular, api, service

In angular 7. I need to send an Array information get it from Itunes Api, which is included in a component called "search", to another component called "catalog". I've understand that in this case I've to use a service which allows to share the info between them. Here's some code. What's wrong?

I've tried with viewchild, input, output, but there's no result; because both components aren't "relatives".

"search"

```
"search" 



import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core'; 
    import { RequestService } from '../../services/request/request.service';
    import {DataShareService} from '../../services/dataShare/data-share.service';
    import { Music } from '../../models/music';

    @Component({
      selector: 'search',
      styleUrls: ['./ion-searchbar.component.sass'],
      templateUrl: './ion-searchbar.component.html',
      providers: [RequestService, DataShareService],
    })
    export class IonSearchBarComponent implements OnInit {
      public searchResults: Music[]; 
      public searchValue: string;

      constructor(public _requestService: RequestService, private _dataShareService: DataShareService) {}

      ngOnInit() {
    this._dataShareService.$sendDataObservable.subscribe(
      data => {
        this.searchResults = data
    })
  }

  sendData(searchResults: Music[]){
    console.log("executat");
    this._dataShareService.sendData(searchResults);
  }

  search(){
    this._requestService.getMusic(this.searchValue).subscribe(
      result => {
        this.searchResults = result.results;
        console.log(result.results);
        this.sendData(this.searchResults);
      },
      error =>{ 
        console.log(<any>error);
      }
    );
  }
}



"service"



import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Music } from '../../models/music';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataShareService {
  private _sendDataSubject = new Subject<Music[]>();
  $sendDataObservable = this._sendDataSubject.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  sendData(data: Music[]){
    this._sendDataSubject.next(data);
    console.log(data);
  }
}



"catalog" 


import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {RequestService} from '../../services/request/request.service';
import {DataShareService} from '../../services/dataShare/data-share.service';
import { Music } from '../../models/music';

@Component({
  selector: 'catalog',
  templateUrl: './catalog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./catalog.component.sass'],
  providers: [RequestService, DataShareService]
})
export class CatalogComponent implements OnInit {
  public title: any;
  public InfoLlegada: any;

  constructor(private _dataShareService: DataShareService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.InfoLlegada)
    this._dataShareService.$sendDataObservable.subscribe(
      data => {
        this.InfoLlegada = data
        console.log(data);
    });

  }
}
```

Comment: You can also import main components in search component and passed the data

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the actual cause, but there an issue with your `this` binding in `getMusic` subscription in `search` component. Try `this.sendData.call(this, result.results);`